Как отключить поиск во вкладке Project IDE JetBrains
Подскажите пожалуйста как отключить этот поиск (см. скриншот).
Суть в том, что он открывается как только я начинаю что-то писать.


Если писать в выделенной вкладкой Project, то так и будет. Нужно просто выделить файл (кликнуть по нему).
